# Using structure map with MSTest

Tags: exception, structuremap, mstest

I have created myself a test project with a single test in it. Within the "TestInitialize" method I'm trying to call my StructureMap setup method where I set which concrete instances should be used for which interfaces.

However as soon as the test tries to run I get a {"Operation could destabilize the runtime."} exception. Without using structuremap it works fine (but obiviously I need it in there).

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what might be causing this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of messing around, I discovered that all I needed to do was to right-click on the StructureMap dll and click "Unblock" and the permissions were sorted.

Comment: I have same issue overhere. How did you "unblock" it?

Comment: right-click on the dll and click properties and there should be an unblock button on the bottom right