# Operation could destabilize the runtime

Tags: c#-4.0, structuremap

System.Security.VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.
....
my site:http://noyaban.com/tara

IoC.cs:

```
public static IContainer Initialize()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.Scan(scan =>
            {
               // scan.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory();
                scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                scan.WithDefaultConventions();
            });
            x.For<IUnitOfWork>().HttpContextScoped().Use<SadeghianDbContext>();
            x.For<IAboutUsService>().Use<AboutUsService>();
            x.For<IBannersService>().Use<BannersService>();
            x.For<ICentralOfficeService>().Use<CentralOfficeService>();
            x.For<IContactUsService>().Use<ContactUsService>();
            x.For<IDownloadsService>().Use<DownloadsService>();
            x.For<ILogoService>().Use<LogoService>();
            x.For<INewsService>().Use<NewsService>();
            x.For<IProductsService>().Use<ProductsService>();
            x.For<IResellerService>().Use<ResellerService>();
            x.For<ISlideShowService>().Use<SlideShowService>();
            x.For<IUsersService>().Use<UsersService>();
            x.For<IProvinceService>().Use<ProvinceService>();
            x.For<IForgottenPasswordService>().Use<ForgottenPasswordService>();
            x.For<IAdminCommentsService>().Use<AdminCommentsService>();
            x.For<IGroupingProductService>().Use<GroupingProductService>();
            x.For<IHomePageBannerService>().Use<HomePageBannerService>();
            x.For<IHomePageFooterService>().Use<HomePageFooterService>();
        });
        return ObjectFactory.Container;
    }
```

this code in local host perfectly work but in host not work!

[image: stack trace]

Comment: Please post the full strack trace.

Comment: Have you unblocked the structuremap dll? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7107372/66849).

Comment: As a side note, since you're scanning with default conventions, you can ditch all For-Use statements except for the `IUnitOfWork`.

Comment: There is a .NET update that fixes this issuer. 

see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683182/operation-could-destabilize-the-runtime-in-structuremap

Answer (score 0):

[image]

i suggest medium trust 
I think this could be related to   medium trust issue