# Operation could destabilize the runtime in StructureMap

Tags: c#, asp.net, structuremap, verificationexception

I am getting this error in one of my ASP.NET 4.5 MVC application on my local machine. Other applications setup with ASP.NET 4.5 and using StructureMap work fine. 
[image: Error Message]

Any help/solution on this would be highly appreciated.
The line of code that causes this is:

```
using StructureMap;
using StructureMap.Graph;

namespace Management.Web.DependencyResolution
{
    public static class IoC
    {
        public static IContainer Initialize()
        {
            ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
            {
                x.Scan(scan =>
                {
                    scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                    scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                    scan.Assembly("Management.Core");
                    scan.Assembly("Management.DAL");
                    scan.Assembly("Management.BusinessServices");
                    scan.Assembly("Management.Infrastructure");
                });
                x.For<INavigationService>().Use<NavigationService>();
            });
            return ObjectFactory.Container;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this update? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2748645 described in more detail here http://elegantcode.com/2012/08/23/net-4-5-operation-could-destabilize-the-runtime-yikes/

Comment: Yes I had. Got the following message : 
Software Update KB2748645 Installation Wizard does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your computer. Please click the link below for more details.

Comment: I was installing the wrong version. Issue Fixed. Thx a lot.

Comment: Hello, I also got the following message : Software Update KB2748645 Installation Wizard does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your computer. Please click the link below for more details. I tried on both x86 and x64 but I got same error. How did you get over this, @MurtuzaB?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a .Net update that fixes this issue.
[KnowledgeBase 2748645](https://web.archive.org/web/20150214082155/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2748645)

> When you use some third-party controls, you may receive a
>   System.Security.VerificationException exception. This issue
>   occurs if the following conditions are true:
>
> The third-party controls use the generic types.
>
> The CLR verifier is enabled by declaring an assembly that is marked as
>   security-transparent.

The issue is described in more detail in [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20161118034636/http://elegantcode.com/2012/08/23/net-4-5-operation-could-destabilize-the-runtime-yikes/).

> The problem exists on the IL level and is only detected when the CLR
>   Verifier is executed on the code. The verifier makes sure that the IL
>   is type safe before it’s sent to the JIT Compiler and if it detects
>   and issue (like this) it will bark at you.

Comment: Is there a similar patch for .NET 4.0?

Comment: Is this fixed in version 4.5.1 or 4.5.2? I'd far rather update the framework on our servers to a supported version than install a hotfix.

Comment: I installed 4.5.1 and the issue is gone.

Comment: I have the same issue, but am using Windows 8.1 which the fix doesn't apply. How can I solve it? thanks

Comment: I have similar exception with structuremap v3. I found that there is no exception if I use [structuremap v2 package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/structuremap/2.6.4.1). May be it because v3 has no strong name but v2 has. Hope this helps anyone.

Comment: For me, it happened because I ran ANTS 8 Performance Profiler for an ASP.NET MVC3 web. Once the profiler is disabled and de-attached, the error gone.

Comment: The link no longer works, it returns a 404. Any workaround?

Comment: @brugnner - Both links have gone away. The best I can do is change the links to point to the web archive, which I just edited into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

KB2748645 does not apply for Windows 8/8.1/10. In this case, you can try : Run -> Turn Windows features on or off -> reinstall .NET Framework 4.5 & IIS .

Note: if you have ANTS 8.5 Performance Profiler, disable & de-attach it.

It helped in my case.