# VerificationException configuring StructureMap 3 Registry

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, structuremap, structuremap3, verificationexception

After updating our working application from StructureMap 2.6.4.1 to StructureMap 3.0.5.130 on an unpatched Windows 2012 Data Center OS, we get the following exception configuring the StructureMap registry from a ASP.NET MVC 4.0 app on .NET 4.0:

```
[VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.]
StructureMap.Util.LightweightCache`2..ctor(IDictionary`2 dictionary) +0
StructureMap.Graph.PluginGraph..ctor() +225
StructureMap.PluginGraphBuilder..ctor() +80
StructureMap.ConfigurationExpression..ctor() +26
StructureMap.PipelineGraph.For(Action`1 action) +26
EnhancementQueue.DependencyResolution.IoC.Initialize() +82
EnhancementQueue.App_Start.StructuremapMvc.Start() +11
```

The same app works fine on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine. Obviously, it is some kind of configuration issue, probably a Windows Update issue, but does anyone know which Windows or .NET update to run? We can't take this machine down and I need to understand the missing dependency.

Comment: Does this happen in production or on your dev machine?

Comment: Production. Based on this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683182/operation-could-destabilize-the-runtime-in-structuremap), I might need to install .NET 4.5 even though I am running on .NET 4.0.