# WCF with StructureMap: Operation could destabilize the runtime

Tags: c#, wcf, ioc-container, structuremap, structuremap3

I encountered this weird error when I used WCF with StructureMap.

I also tried to search the stack and there are some answers that recommend to install a hotfix: [Operation could destabilize the runtime in StructureMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683182/operation-could-destabilize-the-runtime-in-structuremap)

But I cannot install the hotfix due to `"Software Update KB2748645 Installation Wizard does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your computer. Please click the link below for more details."`

```
public class StructureMapInstanceProvider : IInstanceProvider
{
    private readonly Type _serviceType;
    public StructureMapInstanceProvider(Type serviceType)
    {
        _serviceType = serviceType;
    }
    public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, Message message)
    {
        return ObjectFactory.GetInstance(_serviceType); // error thrown here
    }
}
```

---

```
An exception of type 'StructureMap.StructureMapConfigurationException' occurred in StructureMap.dll but was not handled in user code. 
Operation could destabilize the runtime.

Additional information:
Attempting to create a build plan for concrete type ProfileService
1.) Attempting to create a BuildPlan for Instance of ProfileService -- ProfileService
2.) Container.GetInstance(ProfileService)
```

**Stacktrace**

```
   at StructureMap.Building.ConcreteType.SourceFor(String ctorOrSetter, String name, Type dependencyType, Object value) in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\Building\ConcreteType.cs:line 200
   at StructureMap.Building.ConcreteType.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BuildConstructorStep>b__3(ParameterInfo x) in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\Building\ConcreteType.cs:line 112
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at StructureMap.StringExtensions.Each[T](IEnumerable`1 enumerable, Action`1 action) in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\Extensions.cs:line 10
   at StructureMap.Building.ConstructorStep.Add(IEnumerable`1 dependencies) in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\Building\ConstructorStep.cs:line 79
   at StructureMap.Building.ConcreteType.BuildConstructorStep(Type pluggedType, ConstructorInfo constructor, DependencyCollection dependencies, Policies policies) in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\Building\ConcreteType.cs:line 115
   at StructureMap.Building.ConcreteType.BuildSource(Type pluggedType, ConstructorInfo constructor, DependencyCollection dependencies, Policies policies) in c:\BuildAgent\work\996e173a8ceccdca\src\StructureMap\Building\ConcreteType.cs:line 27
```

I really don't understand the error, and I also cannot find where it is from.
So I'm opening for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

After a day of messing around, this is the workaround (not actually a resolution):

In Visual Studio (I'm using 2013), go to:

Tools -> Options -> IntelliTrace -> General -> Unchoose `IntelliTrace events and call information`
(Or Choose `IntelliTrace events only`)

I don't know why this option caused the problem. But this workaround worked fine for me.
You can find a same problem here:
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q512306

**Quoted**

```
outro56 2 years ago
Ok, I think I may have found a workaround as per Q262635, it has to do with IntelliTrace; 
simply changing the IntelliTrace settings to "IntelliTrace events only" was able to get 
around this problem (i.e. Tools->Options->IntelliTrace->General)
```