# The type initializer for 'MimeKit.ParserOptions' threw an exception

Tags: vb.net, mailkit, mimekit

I am testing using an existing System.Net.Mail.MailMessage with MimeKit's support for direct casting to a MimeMessage in addition to using MimeKit's DkimSigner and MailKit's Smtp client.

I am getting "The type initializer for 'MimeKit.ParserOptions' threw an exception." With a stack trace mentioning 'at MimeKit.MimeMessage.CreateFromMailMessage(MailMessage message)'

There is also an Inner Excpetion: "The type initializer for 'MimeKit.Utils.CharsetUtils' threw an exception." Stacktrace: 'at MimeKit.ParserOptions..ctor() at MimeKit.ParserOptions..cctor()

I am not getting any exception on my development box but that only executes up to the conversion and signing not the actual smtp sending.

```
    Dim netMail As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
    netMail.From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("no_reply@lionandlambchurch.com")
    netMail.To.Add(txtTo.Text)
    netMail.Subject = txtSubject.Text
    netMail.Body = txtContent.Text

    Dim mimeMail As MimeMessage = CType(netMail, MimeMessage)

    Dim headersToSign = New List(Of HeaderId)
    headersToSign.Add(HeaderId.From)
    headersToSign.Add(HeaderId.To)
    headersToSign.Add(HeaderId.Subject)
    headersToSign.Add(HeaderId.Date)

    Dim privateKeyPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\App_Data\rsa.private"
    Dim signer = New Cryptography.DkimSigner(privateKeyPath, "lionandlambchurch.com", "key1")

    Dim loggerPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\logs\smtp-mailkit.log"

    mimeMail.Sign(signer, headersToSign, Cryptography.DkimCanonicalizationAlgorithm.Relaxed, Cryptography.DkimCanonicalizationAlgorithm.Simple)

    ' Don't attempt sending locally
    If Request.Url.Host.ToLower().Contains("localhost") Then Return

    Using client As New MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient(New ProtocolLogger(loggerPath))
        client.Connect("relay-hosting.secureserver.net", 25, False)
        If chkAuthenticate.Checked Then
            client.Authenticate("no_reply@lionandlambchurch.com", "****")
        End If
        client.Send(mimeMail)
        client.Disconnect(True)
    End Using
```

Comment: Take a look at this https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/blob/master/MimeKit/Utils/CharsetUtils.cs

Answer (score 2):

Had same problem and I solved it by opening the NuGet console in Visual Studio and installing the newest **System.Text.Encoding.CodePages** package:

`install-Package System.Text.Encoding.CodePages`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the exception, the error is occurring during the conversion, not sending.

For some reason, the static constructor for MimeKit.ParserOptions is failing because the static constructor for MimeKit.Utils.CharsetUtils is failing.

Looking at MimeKit's code, all I can think of is that your server doesn't have UTF-8 or Latin1 support.

e.g. `System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding (65001, new EncoderExceptionFallback (), new DecoderExceptionFallback ());` or `Encoding.GetEncoding (28591, new EncoderExceptionFallback (), new DecoderExceptionFallback ());` is throwing an exception.

Honestly, I don't know how that could even happen.

What .NET are you using on your server?

Comment: This is on a godaddy server. Using .NET 4.5

Comment: Can you confirm that it doesn't have UTF8 and/or Latin1 support?

Comment: I confirmed, their shared windows hosting only supports UTF-8 and not Latin1

Comment: Is it possible for you to get Latin1 support?

Comment: The respoonse I got was their Linux plans will support Latin1, but not the Windows plans,  "There is not a way to add it".

Comment: Okay, so one possible work-around is to use the PCL versions of MimeKit and MailKit because they use my Portable.Text.Encoding library for charset conversion rather than the System encodings.

Comment: I have no previous experience yet with PCL's. Could you rough out the steps needed for that?  I did clone your MimeKit repo locally and opened the MimeKit.sln but it would not open three of the projects including Android, CoreFX, and iOS (I need Xamirin?).  The Portable project would not compile.  I am using Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition Update 4.  I just installed Microsoft.Net Portable Library Reference Assemblies after the first attempt.  Still not building.  Or is there already a compiled PCL version available? What other considerations are there for my web app's build?

Comment: Xamarin is needed for the iOS and Android projects, yes, but you can just disable (or remove) those projects. The CoreFX project requires VS2015 (you can remove it as well). What build error(s) are you getting?

Comment: I installed VS Comunity 2015 and things are building minus the ios/android projects. I am getting the MimeKit.dll and Portable.Text.Encoding.dll from the release build of the portable project.  Can I use this with the MailKit.dll I already got from Nuget?  Not seeing portable being mentioned in the MailKit repo page on github, so I don't need to compile that repo?

Comment: Ewww.... I'm not sure, to be honest. The PCL version of MimeKit was intended to be used with the WindowsPhone version of MailKit (I forgot that I didn't have a true PCL version of MailKit), but it *might* work with the .NET 4.5 version of MailKit as well, I just haven't tested that pairing. The only potential gotcha that I can think of is that MimeKit uses Portable.Text.Encoding while MailKit uses System.Text.Encoding in that scenario, but that might not matter.

Comment: BTW, make sure to reference Portable.Text.Encoding.dll because the PCL MimeKit.dll needs it.

Comment: Since you are using nugets, you *might* be able to edit your `packages.config` and add these: `<package id="MimeKit" version="1.2.21" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8" />
  <package id="Portable.BouncyCastle" version="1.8.0" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wp8" />`

Comment: I'm starting to doubt this will work... I forgot that MailKit also makes use of BouncyCastle and it may not like the PCL BouncyCastle :-\

Comment: If this PCL trick doesn't work, can you find out if `System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding (1252);` works and whether or not `System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding (20127);` works? Maybe I can use one of these as a fallback if `28591` fails.

Comment: I've patched MimeKit on GitHub to recover from a lack of `iso-8859-1` support on the system by trying to first fall back to `windows-1252` and then to `us-ascii`. I'm pretty sure that at least `us-ascii` is part of the core. Would be nice if you could test which of the 2 encodings I listed above are present on your system, though, so that I can be sure that my assumptions are correct.

Comment: I will test those encodings and report back

Comment: System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252) works and System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(20127) works

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This suggests that my work-around should fix things for you. You can probably just build the .NET 4.5 version of MimeKit and drop the MimeKit.dll into your project instead of using the MimeKit nuget (the only change is this work-around).

Comment: I had to patch MailKit in GitHub as well, since it also expects iso-8859-1 to be there, so you'll need to grab that as well. The next release will have these fixes.

Comment: Compiled your code with the patch.  Sorry still seeing the same exceptions in my error logger.  I did however turn off custom exceptions to see the ASP.NET red screen in full.  My error logger evidently only logged two exception levels.  Actually there are three exceptions reported.  The third one and first in the red screen stack trace is

Comment: [VerificationException: Operation could destabilize the runtime.]
   MimeKit.Utils.OptimizedOrdinalIgnoreCaseComparer.GetHashCode(String obj) +17
   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) +66
   MimeKit.Utils.CharsetUtils.AddAliases(Dictionary`2 dict, Int32 codepage, Int32 fallback, String[] names) +81
   MimeKit.Utils.CharsetUtils..cctor() +516

Comment: This may be useful: http://dotnet4hosting.asphostcentral.com/post/SOLVED-Operation-could-destabilize-the-runtime-ASPNET-45-Hosting.aspx

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683182/operation-could-destabilize-the-runtime-in-structuremap